# How can I open a list of URLs on Windows

Tags: windows, shell, scripting, powershell

I'm looking for a way to open a list of URLs in all of my browsers ( Firefox, Chrome, and IE ) on Windows using a scriptable shell such as Powershell or Cygwin.

Ideally I should be able to type in a list of URLs as arguments to the command, i.e. `openUrl http://example.net http://example2.net http://example3.com...

I would also need this script to pass authentication info into the http header (encoded usename and password).

Comment: You want it tabbed too? So three browser windows with 10 tabs? This looks like a problem of figuring out the right commands to pass to {$browser.exe}...

Comment: Yes, It must be tabbed. Although I usually set my browsers to only open in new tabs. And Yes, if only I knew the right commands... I have little experience scripting on Windows.

Answer (score 9):

With chrome it's not hard.

```
$chrome = (gi ~\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe ).FullName
$urls = "stackoverflow.com","slate.com"
$urls | % { & $chrome $_ }
```

Answer (score 7):

First, how to open URLs in PowerShell. In PowerShell open a URL is very simple, just use `start`

```
start http://your.url.com
```

I think you can simple use `foreach` to handle the list of URLs.

Second, pass authentication via URL. There is a standard way for HTTP based authentication. (not HTML form based). You could construct the URL like:

```
http://username:password@your.url.com
```

Again, it only works for HTTP based authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `HKCR\http\shell\open\command` how each browser handles urls. Then just use the normal methods to launch the browsers with appropriate urls.